# Area 51 could use a topbar search box

Tags: feature-request, area-51, search, top-bar

Not all pages on Area 51 have the big shiny red "Search Proposals" banner at the top center of the screen; it's difficult to access search from those other pages unless you know what you're doing (read: [know that `/search` gets you there](http://area51.stackexchange.com/search)). Besides, I recently had to search for something on Area 51, and the spot where the search box usually is greeted me with this highly disconcerting lack of said box:

[image]

It was highly disconcerting.

Comment: Free-hand circles: always works.

Comment: For what it's worth, the old top bar on Area 51 didn't have a search box either. It's by design as far as I know.